# Creating a List of objects from datatable with optional column numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, datatable

I have an MVC web app where users are allowed to upload excel files. The excel files have the following column counts

- File 1 => 10 columns (8 mandatory and 2 optional)
- File 2 => 8 columns (6 mandatory and 2 optional)
- File 3 => 6 columns (5 mandatory and 1 optional)
- File 4 => 4 columns (4 mandatory and 0 optional)

I get passed a `DataTable` which has been populated with the column names based on the excel file that was uploaded. I've gone ahead and created a `class` which has 10 properties as:

```
public class ImportData
{
    public string OpertorName { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Now What I am trying to achieve is create a a `List<ImportData>` from the `DataTable`. I know I can do the following

```
List<ImportData> imports = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
new ImportData
{
   OpertorName = row.Field<string>("OPERTOR NAME"),
   MachineName = row.Field<string>("MACHINE NAME")
   ...
   //all 10 properties
}).ToList();
```

The above works fine for `File 1` but how can I accomodate for the rest of the files because not all of them will have all 10 columns in the `DataTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check if certain column exists and then take column value from `DataTable` or put some default value. Something like this:

```
List<ImportData> imports = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
new ImportData
{
   OpertorName = row.Field<string>("OPERTOR NAME"),
   MachineName = row.Field<string>("MACHINE NAME"),
   SomeOtherProperty = row.Table.Columns.Contains("column_name") ?
       row.Field<string>("column_name") : 
       string.Empty //default value since column_name doesn't exist
   //etc
}).ToList();
```